# Java - If ButtonGroup1 is not selected then show message box

Tags: java, swing, radio-button, boolean, buttongroup

I am working on my college project, where we have to design a program for a Sandwich shop. I am stuck on one place. I want to show the message box if nothing has been selected in `buttongroup1`.

I tried this bit of code but it doesn't seem to be working correctly:

```
boolean ButtonGroup1 = false;
 if (ButtonGroup1 == false)
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "Pleace Selete the Sandwiches order" );``
```

here is the program:

```
private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         


/* Errors -------------------------------*/
    buttonGroup1.add(HamRButton);
    buttonGroup1.add(ChickenRButton);
    buttonGroup1.add(CheeseRButton);
    buttonGroup1.add(PorkRButton);
    buttonGroup1.add(TunaRButton);

    buttonGroup2.add(WaterRButton);
    buttonGroup2.add(BottleofPOP);
    buttonGroup2.add(CanofPoP);

    buttonGroup3.add(CheeseExButton);
    buttonGroup3.add(SaladExButton);
    buttonGroup3.add(HamExButton);
    buttonGroup3.add(TunaExButton);
    buttonGroup3.add(ChickenExButton);
    buttonGroup3.add(PorkExButton);


  boolean buttonGroup1 = false;
  if (!buttonGroup1){
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " ");
  }
```

Comment: What do you mean "not seems to working right"? Also, it's better to write `!buttonGroup1` instead of `== false`. Also try to follow Java naming convention and let variables begin with lower case.

Comment: whenever i am running the program, it showing me the Message dialog box even if i am selecting the radiobuttons and thanks i will follow them from now on.

Comment: @MarounMaroun Could you please tell me? how to sort this out?

Comment: I can't tell anything from the code you posted, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) please

Answer (score 1):

**Step1 :** you need to iterate over all `JRadioButtons` inside `ButtonGroup`.
**Step2 :** cast the exach item of `ButtonGroup` into `JRadioButton`
**Step3:** try to identify the each item ether is selected or not by calling `isSelected()` function.
**Step4:** if any item in ButtonGroup is selected make the boolean variable `buttonGroup1` to `true` and quit the loop.
**Step5:** finally check the `boolean` variable to display the Message

Try This:

```
 boolean buttonGroup1 = false;     
 Enumeration<AbstractButton> allRadioButton=btngroup.getElements();  
 while(allRadioButton.hasMoreElements())  
 {  
   JRadioButton temp=(JRadioButton)allRadioButton.nextElement();  
   if(temp.isSelected())  
   {  
     buttonGroup1 =true;
     break;
   }  
 }
if (!buttonGroup1)
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "Pleace Selete the Sandwiches order" );
```

Comment: Sorry I am a beginner and working on my college project and i haven't come cross to Enumeration yet. Could you please explain bit more with my code example?@MarounMaroun